# Non-animated frames sequences in CSS animations

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, keyframe

Is there a way that CSS3 animations can jump straight between 2 keyframes without tweening?

[In this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/6BLLy/) I'm using Javascript and transitions to slide an element out to the left, reposition it to the right, and slide it back in. The imperative logic goes a bit like this:

1. Turn transitions off and set the translate property to 0.
2. At the end of an instant setTimeout, turn transitions on and set translate to off-screen left
3. On transition end, turn transitions off again and set translate to off-screen right
4. At the end of an instant setTimeout, turn transitions on and set translate to 0

Meanwhile, a CSS animation can only

1. Set translate to 0
2. Set translate to off-screen left
3. Set translate to off-screen right
4. Set translate to 0

Because all properties in the animation are implicitly animated, I don't get to jump between steps 2 & 3 — the best I can do is set the keyframes to be infinitesimally close in the hope that the user doesn't perceive the movement. [This example is functional, but feels like a hack](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/zTQsU/).

```
@-webkit-keyframes slideInOut {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(       0, 0, 0 );
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d( -1920px, 0, 0 );
  }
  50.0001% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(  1920px, 0, 0 );
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(       0, 0, 0 );
  }
}
```

Am I limited to Javascript for solving this, or can it be done using the CSS animations module?

Comment: I think you've actually found the best way of doing it.

Comment: I agree with Jivings, I use this method [all of the time](http://cssdeck.com/labs/falling-circles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this hack

50%: -webkit-transform: translate3d( -1920px, 0, 0 );

50.0001%: -webkit-transform: translate3d( -1920px, 0, 0 ), visibility: hidden; (or opacity: 0)

50.0002%: -webkit-transform: translate3d( 1920px, 0, 0 ), visibility: hidden;

50.0003%: -webkit-transform: translate3d( 1920px, 0, 0 ), visibility: visible;

...

Comment: Excellent thinking — a brief disappearance is better than a brief slide.